# How to remove TFS pull request Reviewers section?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, pull-request

Is it possible to remove this section or to just disable it somehow because developers forget to X-it and whole team gets notification? I already have set automatic reviewers in branch policy.

[image: This is reviewers part i want to remove]

Comment: Can you share your branch policy with the automatic reviewers?

Comment: I dont understand what are you asking. Can you be more precise? I already have branch policy and added automatic reviewers and they are Code Reviewers group. @ShaykiAbramczyk

Answer (score 0):

Remove that group from the reviewers section of the branch policy for that branch.

Comment: The point is that this branch is not even protected. Somewhere is set that when someone create pull request whole project team gets notified about pull request. For example when you have 90 people in a team that is quite annoying. I just need to do it hard way-to disable this part..